Derivation of the ellipse equation
The derivation of the equation of an ellipse is straightforward if we apply one of its important properties that $\displaystyle \frac{AC}{AF_2}=\frac{a}{c}$, where the line BC is its directrix. This simply leads to $\displaystyle \bigg(x-\frac{a^2}{c}\bigg)^2=\frac{a^2}{c^2}\bigg((x-c)^2+y^2\bigg)$, and this is equivalent to $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$.

However, I'm looking for a method that uses PURE GEOMETRY to derive this equation WITHOUT APPLYING PYTHAGORAS THEOREM, and I'm wondering if this is possible. To be more specific, I'm trying to prove the following relationship $\displaystyle \frac{AF}{AG}=\frac{DO}{EO}$, where $OE=a$. If this is proved, we immediately knows that the ellipse is just a circle being "compressed", and the equation can be derived easily.

I've made a lot of attempts, and my idea is to prove that line $EG$, $AD$ and $OF$ will intersect at the same point. However, this seems difficult. The reason may be that the location of point $D$ is not easy to deal with.
Please help if you have any ideas. Please don't use PYTHAGORAS THEOREM or ANALYTIC GEOMETRY. I want a pure geometry solution if possible. By the way, I hope the solution is based on the definition of an ellipse or some properties that can be proved by pure geometry, rather than some properties that can be only proved using pythagoras theorem or analytic geometry. Any help will be appreciated.
By the way, I hope the following link may be helpful to you.

You'll find the proof you want in many old books, see for instance Drew's "Conic sections" (Cor. 1 of Prop. XIII, page 42)

Thanks. This book really helps.

By reading William Henry's book, I finally understand his pure geometry solution. I want to restate the question before I summarize his solution.
Let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be the two focuses of an ellipse. An arbitrary point $A$ on the ellipse satisfies $AF_1+AF_2=2a$. $O$ is the midpoint of $F_1F_2$, where $F_1F_2=2c$. $BC$ is the major axis of the ellipse. Draw a line segmnet $AD$ such that $AD\perp BC$. Find a point $E$ on the line $AD$ such that $OE=OC$. What we're going to prove is that $\displaystyle \frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{b}{a}.$

I will make some changes based on the solution in the book. Let line $BC$ intersect the directrix at point $F$. Find a point $G$ on the directirx such that $AF_2\perp F_2G$, and another point $H$ such that $AH\perp GF$. Then connect $F_2H$ and extend it to $I$ such that $F_1I=F_2I$. Let line $AD$ intersect line $F_2I$ at $J$, line $AG$ and line $DF$ intersect at point $K$, and then find a point $L$ on line $IH$ such that $LK\perp DF$. Connect $EK$, $OI$, $AL$ and $AI$, and $M$ is the intersection point of line $AI$ and $BC$. Finally, extend $AF_2$ to a point $N$ such that $HN\parallel AI$.
First, we will prove that $\triangle AIF_2\sim\triangle HIA$. Since $F_1I=F_2I$ and $O$ is the midpoint of $F_1F_2$, we have $OI\perp OF_2$. This leads to $OI\parallel HF$, and then $\displaystyle \frac{IF_2}{IH}=\frac{OF_2}{OF}=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$. Now since $AI\parallel HN$, we have $\angle N=\angle IAF_2$ and $\displaystyle \frac{AF_2}{AN}=\frac{IF_2}{IH}=\frac{c^2}{a^2}$. Note that $\displaystyle \frac{AH}{AF_2}=\frac{a}{c}$ (this is proved in this link), we have $\displaystyle \frac{AH}{AN}=\frac{AH}{AF_2}\cdot\frac{AF_2}{AN}=\frac{c}{a}=\frac{AF_2}{AH}$. This directly leads to $\triangle AF_2H\sim\triangle AHN$ and thus $\angle N=\angle AHF_2$. Since we've already prove $\angle N=\angle IAF_2$, we have $\angle IAF_2=\angle AHF_2$, and thereby $\triangle AIF_2\sim\triangle HIA$. This leads to $AI^2=IF_2\cdot IH$.
Second, we will demonstrate that $A$, $F_1$, $I$ and $F_2$ are concyclic. With $BC\parallel AH$, we have $\angle F_1F_2I=\angle AHF_2=\angle IAF_2$. On the other hand, $IF_1=IF_2$ leads to $\angle F_1F_2I=\angle F_2F_1I$ and thus $\angle F_2F_1I=\angle IAF_2$. Now we can conclude that $A$, $F_1$, $I$ and $F_2$ are concyclic. The result is that $\angle F_1AI=\angle F_1F_2I=\angle IAF_2$, i,e., $AI$ bisects $\angle F_1AF_2$, and thus $\displaystyle \frac{AF_2}{MF_2}=\frac{AF_1}{MF_1}=\frac{AF_1+AF_2}{MF_1+MF_2}=\frac{a}{c}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{AH}{MF_2}=\frac{AH}{AF_2}\cdot\frac{AF_2}{MF_2}=\frac{a}{c}\cdot\frac{a}{c}=\frac{a^2}{c^2}$.
Third, we will prove that $\triangle IAJ\sim\triangle ILA$. Note that $AF_2\perp F_2G$, and $AH\perp HG$, we know that $A$, $F_2$, $G$ and $H$ are concyclic, and thus $\angle AHF_2=\angle AGF_2$. With $\angle IAF_2=\angle IHA$, we have $\angle AGF_2=\angle IAF_2$. Then $\displaystyle \angle IAG=\angle IAF_2+\angle GAF_2=\angle AGF_2+\angle GAF_2=\pi-\angle AF_2G=\frac{\pi}{2}=\angle DAH$. This is equivalent to $\angle IAJ=\angle GAH$. With $AH\parallel FK$, there are $\angle GAH=\angle AKD$ and $\angle AHF_2=\angle LF_2K$. Therefore $\angle IAJ=\angle AKD$ and $\angle LF_2K=\angle AGF_2.$ Note that $\displaystyle \angle AGF_2+\angle GAF_2=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \angle LF_2K+\angle F_2LK=\frac{\pi}{2}$, and then we have $\angle GAF_2=\angle F_2LK$, which implies $A$, $F_2$, $L$ and $K$ are concyclic. Then $\angle AKD=\angle ALF_2$. Since $\angle IAJ=\angle AKD$, we have $\angle ALF_2=\angle IAJ$, which leads to $\triangle IAJ\sim\triangle ILA$. Thus we have $AI^2=IJ\cdot IL$. With the already proved fact that $AI^2=IF_2\cdot IH$, we have $IJ\cdot IL=IF_2\cdot IH$. Note that $\displaystyle \frac{IL}{OK}=\frac{IH}{OF}=\frac{IF_2}{OF_2}=\frac{IJ}{OD}$, and thus $OD\cdot OK=OF_2\cdot OF=a^2$.
Up to now, in fact the ellipse equation can already be calculated. Now $\displaystyle OK=\frac{a^2}{OD}$, $\displaystyle DK=OK-OD=\frac{a^2}{OD}-OD$, $\displaystyle FK=OK-OF=\frac{a^2}{OD}-\frac{a^2}{c}$, and thus $\displaystyle \frac{AD}{GF}=\frac{DK}{FK}=\frac{c(a^2-OD^2)}{a^2(c-OD)}$. On the other hand, since $\displaystyle \angle ADF_2=\angle AF_2g=\angle F_2FG=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\triangle ADF_2\sim\triangle F_2FG$, which leads to $\displaystyle AD\cdot GF=DF_2\cdot FF_2=(c-OD)\frac{b^2}{c}$. Then $\displaystyle AD^2=AD\cdot GF\cdot\frac{AD}{GF}=\frac{c(a^2-OD^2)}{a^2(c-OD)}\cdot (c-OD)\frac{b^2}{c}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}(a^2-OD^2)$.
However, we can do it in a different way. Since $OD\cdot OK=a^2=OC^2=OE^2$, there is $\triangle DOE\sim\triangle EOK$. Then $\displaystyle \angle OEK=\angle ODE=\frac{\pi}{2}$. The result is that $\triangle ODE\sim\triangle EDK$, and thus $ED^2=OD\cdot DK$. Similarly, we have $\triangle MDA\sim\triangle ADK$, and thus $AD^2=MD\cdot DK$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{AD^2}{ED^2}=\frac{MD}{OD}$. With the proved fact that $\displaystyle \frac{AH}{MF_2}=\frac{a^2}{c^2}$, and $\displaystyle AH=OF-OD=\frac{a^2}{c}-OD$, we have $\displaystyle MF_2=c-\frac{c^2}{a^2}OD$. Then $\displaystyle MD=MF_2+OD-OF_2=c-\frac{c^2}{a^2}OD+OD-c=\frac{b^2}{a^2}OD$, and thus $\displaystyle \frac{AD^2}{ED^2}=\frac{MD}{OD}=\frac{b^2}{a^2}$, which implies $\displaystyle \frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{b}{a}$. The proof is completed.
